# How to update values automatically in table 2, when new values occurs in table 1

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am creating a query, wherein i have created select query from table 1 and then inserting values to table 2, but how can create a command that when new data comes in table 1 then update table 2 values
and this insertion happen daily with job.

I tried creating trigger but i don t know how i can relate this to my scenario

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#temp')IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #temp

Select Getdate()[Data Till],Sum[Quantity] Qty 
into #temp from  XYZ w
here w.Date <=Getdate()

Insert into dbo.table1
Select [Data Till],Qty  from #temp >
```

As of now data is coming in table 2 like

```
1)[Data Till]-2019/05/22  Qty-100 
2)[Data Till]-2019/05/23  Qty-150
3)[Data Till]-2019/05/24  Qty-120
```

Now what if in 2019/05/22 back dated entry of qty -20 comes in table 1 and how will table 2 has to update values in table 2

```
1)[Data Till]-2019/05/22  Qty-80
2)[Data Till]-2019/05/23  Qty-150
3)[Data Till]-2019/05/24  Qty-120
```

Comment: Are you using MySql or sql-server 2008?? Because they are not the same. Please, tag correctly your questions

Comment: @nacho the query is definitely not MySQL. I've removed that tag.

Comment: The trigger is the right way to go. You might need to create different triggers for Create and Update, of course.

Comment: @nacho i am mssqlserver

Comment: @ Markus Deibel Sir can you please help me with trigger i tried creating

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER test
   ON  S.table1 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS UPDATE S.amt SET Sdate = GETDATE() FROM inserted WHERE i.date = S.data
GO

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Sir can you please help me with trigger i tried creating

Comment: Please add the trigger code to the question (and remove the comment) to have everything in one place.

Comment: What does the table schema look like?

Answer (score 0):

**AS MY ASSUMPTION**
 Update means you have the data in table 2 already. If the new data comes in table 1 what kind of update you want to do ? 
 is it existing data update or new record insert then update. 
From your question if it is updated above two kinds of things can be happened 
For this why you have two write insert trigger

```
create trigger abc  
on table1
For insert 
as
begin

--update table2



end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [schema_name.]trigger_name
ON Table_name
AFTER  INSERT
AS
BEGIN
-- write your update statement here
END
```

This is how you can write after update trigger that executes your statement between 'BEGIN' and 'END' when you insert new row into 'Table_name'.